# How does WordPress calculate the new dimensions of the images uploaded

Tags: wordpress, image, formula, image-size

My image sizes in the media settings are:

`150x150`,
`350x350`,
`1000x1000`

- I uploaded a 1000x1002 image and it generated 998x1000 so it's correct as the height which is 1002 is bigger than 1000 so it generated that.
- Then I uploaded a 1000x1001 image that didn't generate for the size 1000! OK, maybe there is a problem here because same as the previous one its height which is 1001, is bigger than 1000. I said maybe it doesn't care 1px!
- And lastly, I uploaded a 1000x1000 image and SURPRISINGLY it generated the 1000x1000!!

Is it a bug? What's its formula?

Answer (score 0):

The function `wp_constrain_dimensions` in `/wordpress/wp-includes` on line 433 in WordPress version 6.0 was the one I was looking for.